# Why doesn't it show a picture of the reddit post in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, reddit

Here's the code currently that i'm using
it logs the picture in the console but not on the embed itself but it doesn't actually put the image from the log itself to the embed is there anything that i can do to change it?
i want it to keep it as an embed

```js
} else if (message.content.startsWith('"meme')) {
        https.get(url, (result) => {
            var body = ''
            result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk
            })

            result.on('end', () => {
                var response = JSON.parse(body)
                var index = response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {

                    var text = index.selftext
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor(9384170)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }

                var image = index.preview.images[0].source.url
                var title = index.title
                var link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink
                var subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {
                    const textembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor(9384170)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }
                console.log(image);
                const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(subRedditName)
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setColor(9384170)
                    .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})`)
                    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)
                message.channel.send(imageembed)
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Got an error: ', e)
            })
        })




        return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preview image url returns **403 forbidden** for some reason. To get the real image url use this:

```js
var image = index.url;
```

Then it should work. I use it my discord.js reddit bot and it works pretty well.